# Method to not catch element in cypress test everytime its needed

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am writing tests for Dark Mode Actions in cypress and I am operating mostly on header. Because of it I am catching it very often using cy.get("header). I am wondering if there is any way to save it in any variable so there is no need to catch it every time and use something like header.contains for example. Documentation of cypress says that simple const header = cy.get("header") doesn't work. Do you know any method to solve this problem so my code will be a little bit cleaner?

**Part of test code**

```
  it("toggles darkmode", () => {
    //when
    cy.visit("localhost:3000");
    cy.get("header").contains("title", "moon-icon").click({ force: true });
    cy.get("header").should("contain", "sun-icon");
    cy.get("header").contains("title", "sun-icon").click({ force: true });
    cy.get("header").should("contain", "moon-icon");
  });
  it("remebers dark mode after refresh", () => {
    //when
    cy.visit("localhost:3000");
    cy.get("header").contains("title", "moon-icon").click({ force: true });
    cy.reload();
    //then
    cy.get("header").should("contain", "sun-icon");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your tests in this same describe block have the same setup, you could alias the `cy.get('header')` in a beforeEach.

```js
describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('localhost:3000');
    cy.get('header').as('header');
  });

  it("toggles darkmode", () => {
    //when
    cy.get("@header").contains("title", "moon-icon").click({ force: true });
    cy.get("@header").should("contain", "sun-icon");
    cy.get("@header").contains("title", "sun-icon").click({ force: true });
    cy.get("@header").should("contain", "moon-icon");
  });
});
```

Comment: But what would it change? I would just have cy.get("@header) instead of cy.get("header), right?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [.within()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Examples) to set scope of commands.

```js
cy.get("header").within($header => {
  cy.contains("title", "moon-icon")
    .click()
    .should("contain", "sun-icon")

  cy.contains("title", "sun-icon")
    .click()
    .should("contain", "moon-icon")
})
```